# Another way to represent the voltage of a PV array in change of irradiance and temperature?

Tags: solar-cell, math, simulink

I am working on a PV array on simulink and I need help on a math question.

On the article I'm basing the model on, the model voltage equation is 
`Vm = VmT - (5- G/0.2)` for the voltage to vary in irradiance and not just temperature `Vmt = Voc*Cv*(Tm-Tr)`;

- Voc= module open circuit voltage at STC (44.9V);
- Cv = temp coefficient(-0.0031);
- Tm = module operating temp;
- Tr = module reference (STC) temp(25 degrees  Celsius).
- Tm varies in time, starts at 27 degrees to 36 back down to 27.
- G (irradiance) is suppose to vary in time as well starting at 1 to 1000 then back to 1.

When I represent that equation in simulink, I get a very high voltage which is not correct. I even search everywhere on google to help me find answers but had no luck. I will have the paragraph stated below what the article says about that equation.

Does anyone know another way I represent the voltage in change of irradiance and temperature?

**Article paragraph**
In a similar way, the PV module voltage as a function of temperature is given by `Vm = Voc + V mT` (12)

where `VmT = VocCv(Tm - Tr)` is module voltage at temperature `T`.

- Voc = module open circuit voltage at STC.
- Cv = module voltage temperature coefficient given by datasheet.

Changes in V due to variations in G are ignored in (12), as pointed out earlier change in irradiance does not change voltage significantly. Beside a correction term that can modify and correct `VmI`, as a function of irradiance, can be included by careful inspection of the VI curves. VI curves show that change in V due to variations of `G` in the operational range is less than 5V and thus a correction term that can modify and correct `VmT` by o to 5V as a function of irradiance can be included as `Vm= VmT - (5 - G/O.2)` (13)

http://www.canadiansolar.com/fileadmin/user_upload/downloads/datasheets/v5.4/Canadian_Solar-Datasheet-CS6XP_Maxpower-v5.4C1en.pdf For VI curves

Comment: I feel you're missing some relevant detail here that would explain what the problem is, but can't suggest what that might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation

```
          Vmt = VocCv(Tm-Tr)
```

is just plain wrong.

You need to intelligently compare the curves and the formula instead of blindly plugging things in and being puzzled.

You cane see from the AV at various temperature curves (right hand graph) that Voc ~= 48V at 5 degrees C and about 38V at 65 degrees C. ie it decreases by 10V as temperature increases by 60 C.
So a 1st approximation is
Voc = 48 - 10 x (T-5)/60
So at 5C Voc = 48 - 10 x (5-5)/60 = 48v  and
at 65C   Voc = 48 - 10 x (65-5)/60 = 48-10 = 38V.

Look at the formulae you have and see how they can be made to reflect the graph based result.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I definitely need to take time to compare the equations with the graph. Thank you so much!